# Is there a faster method of decrypting RSA via javascript than cryptico

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) to encrypt and decrypt data, but when decrypting 3-4 piece of data at once, cryptico can take up to 10 seconds and freezes the browser. Is there any faster way to decrypt RSA data using javascript?

Comment: Show the code you're using to encrypt and decrypt.  Many crypto algorithms are slow by design to mitigate brute-force attacks

Comment: Cryto algorithms are built into most browsers nowadays, so they should be faster than a lib that's not been updated for over 7 years.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt  And if you do want to support older browsers, you would of course poly-fill.

Comment: @Keith would you be able to write me up and quick example on how to encrypt some text using that method with rsa? I quite new to encryption and cant find and good examples on how to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit cyrto algorithms is not my strong point..

But using details from here -> https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples

I've knocked up a little snippet that encodes and then decodes a message.

```js
async function test() {

  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"},
    },
    false, 
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );
  
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode("some private message..");
  
  const enc_data = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    { name: "RSA-OAEP" },
    key.publicKey,
    data 
  );
  
  const dec_data = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    { name: "RSA-OAEP" },
    key.privateKey, 
    enc_data
  );
  
  const decoded = new TextDecoder().decode(dec_data);
  
  console.log(decoded);
}   

test();
```